# What is a good name for aggregates of code pieces?

Tags: module, repository, package

I'm developing a small project, which is intended to be a prototype of a development environment. The prototype consists only of two data types: Code pieces and test cases. There is no intention the solve software design issues, the intention is only to manage source code in another way than traditional source files. An example aggregate could consist af functions, classes, configuration files, etc.

So my question is now what to name these aggregates of code pieces. These pieces can be functions, classes, etc., and are language-agnostic. My first idea was to name them modules, but i realized that this has special meaning in some programming languages, and naming the concepts in my project correctly is of special interest to me. So I looked for alternatives: components, packages, units. Which all have special meaning depending on programming language and tradition.

I'd like to get input into what would be a good word for describing these aggregations of code pieces, which is very fundamental in software developemnt. I'd like to hear what consensus might be on this matter.